# How to open a NAS Synology port for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, synology

I am new and want to start using Node.js.
I try to run an “Hello, world!” on Synology:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3001;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

This code runs:

```
~$ node app.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3001/
```

But nothing was found when accessing Synology:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I found the instruction:

> Open Firewall-Port on Synology depending on which port you are going to run your xxx (e.g. 3001)

OR

> Create volume1/path_to_your_app/app.js and let the http server listen to port 8080.

Where is this setting on Synology?

Answer (score 2):

Your 127.0.0.1 needs to be the IP address of your NAS.  If you are on your router locally and you have your NAS set to for example 192.168.3.10, then your code would be:

```
const hostname = '192.168.3.10';
const port = 3001;
```

Then in your web browser you would type 192.168.3.10:3001 after running app.js

Answer (score 1):

-> go to `Control panel`, then `Firewall`, `Firewall-profile`. There you can edit your firewall-rules and alternatively add or remove rules.

I hope this is what you are searching for. Otherwise write what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use only LAN.